# JxBrowser not Properly Loading Fonts from EXE

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, jxbrowser

I am attempting to load the Glyphicons font files associated with Bootstrap 3 into JxBrowser, however, the network requests appear to be timing out and getting canceled by Chromium. See screenshot of devtools linked below. Observed with Java 1.8.0_121, JxBrowser 6.14.2 using JavaFX.

I do not encounter this problem from a dev environment, i.e. reading Bootstrap and the associated font files directly from the file system. It only occurs when attempting to load the files from an EXE, and more explicitly, whenever the request is initiated from CSS via a `@font-face` call. I attempted to preload the font from HTML using:

`<link rel="preload" as="font" type="font/woff2" href="path/to/resource/in/exe">`

That appears to have worked as can be seen from the 200 response also in the screenshot linked below. However, Bootstrap appears to be unaware the font loaded and attempts to load the font itself which subsequently fails.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EV0Hk.jpg

Answer (score 1):

According to the screenshot, the relative path points to a resource located inside a JAR archive. Please note that Chromium cannot load resources from an archive such as JAR. You have two options:

1. Extract the required resources to a directory and load them from this directory.
2. Implement a custom protocol handler that will intercept the URL requests to the jar:// resources, reads the content of the required resource using the standard Java API, and sends a response to the web page as it was sent from a web server. For more details, please see the example at https://github.com/TeamDev-IP/JxBrowser-Examples/blob/master/network/src/main/java/JarProtocolHandler.java

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thank you for the response. I use option 2 for the rest of my static files (HTML, JS, and CSS) and have not had an issue. However, the protocol handler was not being used by JxBrowser for the @font-face rule invocations originating from CSS. As a result, I now just extract font files separately as you suggested in option 1.